# Trying to create a trigger based on day and time

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger which would prevent insertions, updates and deletions if done outside office hours(i.e, other than 8-18 hours or sundays)

here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOLIDAY
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF ((EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE)='SUNDAY') OR (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 18)) THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'ILLEGAL OPERATION - OUT OF OFFICE HOURS OR HOLIDAY!');
 END IF ;
END; 
/
```

the trigger was created.
Today is sunday and when i try to insert a row, the application  error is not raise, instead, what i get is:

```
SQL> @/home/divya/A43.SQL

Trigger created.

SQL> DELETE FROM DEPT WHERE D_NO = 'D3' ;
DELETE FROM DEPT WHERE D_NO = 'D3'
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "DIVYA12345.HOLIDAY", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DIVYA12345.HOLIDAY'
```

Can someeone please tell me exactly what is the error? show errors displays - no errors as output. Any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, the logic needs to be fixed too. This code WILL allow an insertion at 18:45 because the hour IS between 8 and 18.

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE)` returns the number of the day in month, not its name. To retrieve the name, you can use `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DAY')` instead, or `to_char(sysdate,'fmDY', 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH')` as suggested in the comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOLIDAY
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON DEPT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (TO_CHAR(sysdate,'fmDY', 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH')='SUNDAY') OR (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM LOCALTIMESTAMP) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 18)) THEN
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'ILLEGAL OPERATION - OUT OF OFFICE HOURS OR HOLIDAY!');
END IF ;
END; 
/
```

Comment: To be extra safe, I'd use `to_char(sysdate,'fmDY', 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH')`. Otherwise an end user with different session date settings could get past the trigger.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson is correct but not for the reason he states :) in fact, you need to use `fm` because `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DAY')` does NOT equal `'SUNDAY'` - `DAY` is padded with spaces so it actually equals `'SUNDAY   '`

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - you're right. I knew there was a second reason why I always use `fmDy` for this. But it's worth specifying a language, in case a user with a French desktop runs it on a Dimanche :)